# Write a minimal custom operator: std::sort requires std::__lg to be degined for my type

Tags: c++, iterator, standard-library

As an exercise, I'm trying to write a custom iterator to be used by [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). From its doc, I read:

> [My iterator] must meet the requirements of [ValueSwappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable) and
>   [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).

Without fully implementing those<sup>1</sup>, I've come to this MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct mcve_random_access_iterator
{
    using size_type  = std::size_t;
    using value_type = int;

    size_type _index;
    value_type* _values;
    mcve_random_access_iterator(value_type* values) : _index(0), _values(values) {}

    mcve_random_access_iterator& operator-(const mcve_random_access_iterator& rhs) { _index-=rhs._index ; return *this; }
    value_type& operator*() { return _values[_index]; }
    friend bool operator==(mcve_random_access_iterator& lhs, mcve_random_access_iterator& rhs) { return lhs._index == rhs._index; }
    friend bool operator!=(mcve_random_access_iterator& lhs, mcve_random_access_iterator& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
};

void swap(mcve_random_access_iterator& lhs, mcve_random_access_iterator& rhs)
{
    std::swap(*lhs, *rhs);
}

struct mcve_container
{
    int _values[3];
    mcve_container() : _values{2, 3, 1} {}
    mcve_random_access_iterator begin() { return {_values}; }
    mcve_random_access_iterator end()  { auto b = begin(); b._index = sizeof(_values)/sizeof(_values[0]); return b; }
};

int main()
{
    mcve_container data;
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    for (auto n : data._values)
        std::cout << n << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Compiling with g++ 7.2.0, I get the following error:

> ```
> /usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1969:14: error: no matching function for call to '__lg(mcve_random_access_iterator&)'
> std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
> ```

<kbd>[demo from coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04804123391f6015)</kbd>

**Why do I get this error and how to address it?**

---

<sup>1)</sup> I've stripped all requirements of RandomAccessIterator from `mcve_random_access_iterator` which still reproduce the error.

Comment: Nice job at reducing the example. Made me realise the actual problem way more quickly.

Comment: You are not *any kind of* Iterator if you don't provide *all of* `value_type`, `difference_type`, `reference`, `pointer`, `iterator_category` (either directly or by providing a specialisation of `std::iterator_traits`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A difference between two RandomAccessIterators is a number of type `std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type` (specifically, a number describing how many elements are between one iterator and the other). Yours isn't.

`std::__lg` is a red herring, the relevant part is that it expects a different type than your `__last - __first` provides.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator (see the requirement corresponding to the expression `b - a`)

Comment: You're right, it was indeed the `operator-` missing in my complete implementation. See minimal _working_ example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9243d89e2b4c34e

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer from @milleniumbug: Here is a minimal working implementation of a custom iterator suitable for `std::sort`.

```
struct random_access_iterator
{
    using size_type  = std::size_t;
    using value_type = int;
    using difference_type = std::size_t;
    using reference = int&;

    size_type _index;
    value_type* _values;


    random_access_iterator(value_type* values) : _index(0), _values(values) {}
    random_access_iterator(random_access_iterator const& other) : _index(other._index), _values(other._values) {}
    random_access_iterator& operator=(random_access_iterator const& other) { _index = other._index ; _values = other._values; return *this;}

    // Iterator
    value_type& operator*() { return _values[_index]; }
    random_access_iterator& operator++() { ++_index; return *this; }

    // InputIterator
    friend bool operator==(random_access_iterator& lhs, random_access_iterator& rhs) { return lhs._index == rhs._index; }
    friend bool operator!=(random_access_iterator& lhs, random_access_iterator& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
    value_type& operator->() { return _values[_index]; }
    random_access_iterator operator++(int) { const auto tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp; }

    // ForwardIterator
    random_access_iterator() : _index(0), _values(nullptr) {}    

    // BidirectionalIterator
    random_access_iterator& operator--() { --_index; return *this; }
    random_access_iterator operator--(int) { const auto tmp = *this; --*this; return tmp; }

    // RandomAccessIterator
    random_access_iterator& operator+=(difference_type rhs) { _index+=rhs; return *this; }
    friend random_access_iterator operator+(random_access_iterator const& lhs, difference_type rhs) { auto tmp = lhs; tmp+=rhs; return tmp; }
    friend random_access_iterator operator+(difference_type lhs, random_access_iterator const& rhs) { return rhs + lhs; }

    random_access_iterator& operator-=(difference_type rhs) { _index-=rhs; return *this; }
    friend random_access_iterator operator-(random_access_iterator const& lhs, difference_type rhs) { auto tmp = lhs; tmp-=rhs; return tmp; }
    friend random_access_iterator operator-(difference_type lhs, random_access_iterator const& rhs) { return rhs - lhs; }
    friend difference_type operator-(random_access_iterator const& lhs, random_access_iterator const& rhs) { return lhs._index - rhs._index; }

    reference operator[](size_type i) const { return *(*this + i); }

    friend bool operator<(random_access_iterator const& lhs, random_access_iterator const& rhs) { return lhs._index < rhs._index; }
    friend bool operator<=(random_access_iterator const& lhs, random_access_iterator const& rhs) { return lhs._index <= rhs._index; }
    friend bool operator>(random_access_iterator const& lhs, random_access_iterator const& rhs) { return lhs._index > rhs._index; }
    friend bool operator>=(random_access_iterator const& lhs, random_access_iterator const& rhs) { return lhs._index >= rhs._index; }
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct iterator_traits<random_access_iterator>
    {
        using size_type         = random_access_iterator::size_type;
        using value_type        = random_access_iterator::value_type;
        using difference_type   = random_access_iterator::difference_type;
        using reference         = random_access_iterator::reference;
        using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;
    };
}

void swap(random_access_iterator& lhs, random_access_iterator& rhs)
{
    std::swap(*lhs, *rhs);
}
```

I've written a simple live demo to see [this iterator in action with `std::sort`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9243d89e2b4c34e).